# Logic for snake tail in c

Tags: c, logic

I am new to C programming and found a code for snake game but I am unable to understand the logic part for tail creation here is code

```
void Logic()
{
    int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    tailX[0] = x;
    tailY[0] = y;
    for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
    {
        prev2X = tailX[i];
        prev2Y = tailY[i];
        tailX[i] = prevX;
        tailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;
    }
```

Actually I am not understanding **for** loop part, by the way according to my understanding , in first iteration

1) `prev2X = tailX[1] // prev2X = 0`

2) `prev2Y = tailY[1] // again 0`

3) `tailX[1] = prevX // assuming value of prevX 5`

4) `tailY[1] = prevY // assuming value of prevY 6`

5) `prevX = prev2X // prevX =0`

6) `prevY = prev2Y // again 0`

In second iteration

1) `prev2X = tailX[2] // prev2X = 0`

2) `prev2Y = tailY[2] // again 0`

3) `tailX[1] = prevX // prevX is 0 bcz of 1st iteration`

4) `tailY[1] = prevY // same 0`

5) `prevX = prev2X // 0`

6) `prevY = prev2Y // again 0`

But I know it is wrong so how this logic is working please explain step by step  at least for 2 iterations

Comment: This is a convoluted way of shifting the `tailX` and `tailY` arrays by 1, and putting a new value in the 0 index.

Comment: I would rather use a "ring" buffer and keep the index of the "head". So each step only only one value has to change.

Comment: I can implement other logic like your logic but I want to know how above code logic is working bcz each time zero is assigned so how x and y coordinates were generated

Comment: No zero is assigned anywhere in the code posted.

Comment: tailX[1] is equals to zero because default value of uninitialized global variables is zero so zero is assigned to prev2X and prev2Y that's why I am confusing

Comment: You forgot about `int prevX = tailX[0];
    int prevY = tailY[0];`. And these are set from `x` and `y`.

Comment: OK  you are right `prevX=tailX[0]` will not equal to zero but in __for__ loop last line `prevX=prev2X ` is equals to what ? I think zero ? I am still confused 